# How to combine two columns of different datasets in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames in R: A & B. A contains one column ("X1") with 138 obs. and B contains one column ("term") with 520 obs. I want to combine both into one new dataframe with only one column, which thus will contain 138+520=658 observations.

My data:

A:

```
         X1
1       word1
2       word2
3       word3
4       word4
.
.
138     word138
```

B:

```
        term
1       word139
2       word140
3       word141
4       word142
.
.
520     word658
```

They are all different words (from both sets). I want to create a new dataset ("C") which will look like:

```
         X
1       word1
2       word2
3       word3
4       word4
.
.
139     word139
.
.
658     word658
```

Comment: You can use either `rbind` or `merge`, depends on what exactly you're after. If you provide a reproducible example or at least an informative summary of your data, we could help more.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik does this help?

Comment: You got your answer, so I'm going to venture a guess that it worked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rbind` after ensuring that they both have the same names:

```
 C <- rbind(setNames(A, 'X'), setNames(B, 'X'))
```

Another way is to concatenate the two:

```
 C <- data.frame(X = c(A$X1, B$term))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `bind_rows` after renaming the colnames to `X`

```
library(dplyr)

colnames(A) <- "X"
colnames(B) <- "X"
bind_rows(A, B)
```